# Unable to use values.yaml generated as is to upgrade my k8s cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, airflow

Kubernetes Newbie here.

I was following a [youtube tutorial from Marc Lamberti](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDOw8ByzMyY) on how to install airflow using Kubernetes locally - using Kind. I was able to create the k8s cluster using below commands:

```
kind create cluster --name airflow-cluster --config kind-cluster.yaml

helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
helm repo update

kubectl create namespace airflow
helm install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow --debug

# Port forward 
kubectl port-forward svc/airflow-webserver 8080:8080 -n airflow --context kind-airflow-cluster
```

The next part was to upgrade the generate values.yaml using below command

```
helm show values apache-airflow/airflow > values.yaml
```

The next step was to modify this values.yaml and run a `helm upgrade`, however, whether I modify the values.yaml file or not, I am getting the below error:

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -n airflow -f values.yaml --debug
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release airflow
upgrade.go:144: [debug] preparing upgrade for airflow
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: execution error at (airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/secrets.yaml:20:15):
PASSWORDS ERROR: The secret "airflow-postgresql" does not contain the key "password"

helm.go:84: [debug] execution error at (airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/secrets.yaml:20:15):
PASSWORDS ERROR: The secret "airflow-postgresql" does not contain the key "password"

UPGRADE FAILED
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:203
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:1044
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:968
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_arm64.s:1172
```

On examining the secret `airflow-postgresql`, I found that it had `postgres-password` in data, but not `password`, so I added it.

```
$ k describe secret airflow-postgresql
Name:         airflow-postgresql
Namespace:    airflow
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
              helm.sh/chart=postgresql-12.1.9
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: airflow
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: airflow

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
postgres-password:  8 bytes
```

How I added the password -

```
export POSTGRES_PASS=$(kubectl get secret airflow-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgres-password}" | base64 --decode)

k create secret generic airflow-postgresql --from-literal=password=$POSTGRES_PASS --dry-run=client -o yaml | k apply -f -
```

I added the password data to the secret and re-tried. This time I did not have the same error, but the postgres pod went into `CrashLoop Backoff` and I can see in the logs of the pod that the pod is shutting down.

```
│ postgresql 23:36:12.33 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **                                                          ││ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.348 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized                                                 │
│ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.349 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432                                ││ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.349 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432                                     │
│ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.350 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"                                 ││ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.356 GMT [95] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-04-04 23:36:12 GMT                     │
│ 2023-04-04 23:36:12.360 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections                                ││ 2023-04-04 23:37:42.055 GMT [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request                                               │
│ 2023-04-04 23:37:42.066 GMT [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 101) exited with exit c ││ 2023-04-04 23:37:42.066 GMT [96] LOG:  shutting down                                                                │
│ 2023-04-04 23:37:42.076 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is shut down                                                  ││ Stream closed EOF for airflow/airflow-postgresql-0 (postgresql)                                                     │
```

Due to the above, other pods - scheduler, webserver are not able to connect to the DB and are in `CrashLoopBackoff` state as well. (I could see in their logs that there were last trying to connect to the DB)

I am not sure what I need to do to be able to use values.yaml to upgrade the helm chart to a new version.

Many thanks for reading so far. Any guidance would be really appreciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the official manual https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_show_values/, `helm show values` only show the original values based on its original `chart`.

Since you are not specifying the chart version, your `install` command might use different version from `install --upgrade` command.

The right way to upgrade your installation is get `helm release` values from your installation and `compare` it with the `values.yaml` from new `chart version` and adjust the new required `value`.

Some step might be helpful:

###### Step1: Get the chart version you've installed: `helm -n airflow list`, you'll see something as following(my release `tooljet` for example):

```
tooljet         it              12              2023-03-17 21:03:42.9213007 +0800 CST   deployed        app-0.7.7               0.1.0
```

> Here `app-0.7.7` means chart name is `app` and chart version is `0.7.7`.

###### Step2: Fetch the chart values of your previous installed helm release: `helm show values apache-airflow/airflow --version=0.7.7 > values-old.yaml` (remember to change `0.7.7` to your `helm release` version as showed in `step1`)

###### Step3: Fetch the latest chart vaues: `helm show values apache-airflow/airflow > values-new.yaml`

###### Step4: Compared `values-old.yaml` and `values-new.yaml` to find out what `values` are newly required from new chart. Now you can add missing values in `values-old.yaml` and using it in your `helm upgrade --install airflow apache/airflow -f values-old.yaml` command.

---

**WARN**: If you've changed the chart values, you'd better to merge `values.yaml` from your `helm release`, you can get its effective `values` from command: `helm -n airflow get values airflow > values-effect.yaml`. Now your final values should contains values merged from `values-old.yaml`, `values-effect.yaml` and `missing new required values`.

Comment: Thanks @GeminiKeith for your response. However, for me values-old.yaml and values-new.yaml are exactly the same and `helm get values` gives `USER-SUPPLIED VALUES: null`. Hence, it looks more like `helm upgrade` should not have resulted the error that I got without making any changes to the values-old.yaml / values-new.yaml file.

Comment: Hmm, it is weired. However, could you please check the `release` chart version?

Comment: Thanks @Horsing for your response. I checked the versions - I was using the latest helm chart version for airflow - 1.8.0. I tried to use v1.7.0 and everything worked. Tried the same steps with v1.8.0 and it didnt. I yet to dive into why v1.8.0 does not work, but atleast its a start. :-)

Comment: @Moni Wow, it's a big step that we can know more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I had the same issue like you. and I also fix the problem to change the version from 1.8.0 to 1.7.0. :)